# I have a doupt on after update return to list it will go to the initial page

Tags: javascript, jquery

| Item | Stock | Description | Action 
| Book | 5     | PHP Books   | Edit
| Pen  | 14    | Gold Pen    | Edit
| Pen2 | 2     | Silver Pen  | Edit

|Previous|1|2|**3**|4|5|Next|

i have some items in my table on page 3, i wanna edit an item and when i click save the data, i wanna return to this table with same page.

now, when i click save, i will return to page 1

please solve my problem 
its in jquery with pagination paarameters(page=1,limit=10,from=0)

Comment: set class like active-page on pagination element and when you click save get that active-page value by jquery or javascript and send it with param (page=$('.active-page').val(), limit=10,from=0)

Comment: can u please explain breafly ,,,if i update a list after update it returning to a list with initial pagination parameter that scenerio please explain me